# Processing large files on Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am writing an android app which requires me to process a very large file(say 50MB). The file contains three entries-A userid, artistid and the number of times the user has listened to that artist. So now I write the code to find out who the most popular artist is based on the number of times the artist has been heard. I achieve this by hashmapping each of the artist id(key) and then the number of times he's been heard (value).
The code works fine as long as the file is below 20B (I run the app on Nexus S 4g, so the heap is 32MB), but I get an 'Out of memory' error for larger files. I realize the code is very badly written. Any suggestions as to how I could get through this problem!

```
while ((text = inRd.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                int userid = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                artistid = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                int no_times = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                if (hm.containsKey(artistid)) {
                    Integer oldval = (Integer) hm.get(artistid);
                    Integer newval = no_times + oldval;
                    hm.remove(artistid);
                    hm.put(artistid, newval);
                } else
                    hm.put(artistid, no_times);
            }
        }
```

Comment: why don't you convert your file´s data into sqlite and do whatever you want?

Comment: I wasn't aware of sqlite.. I'll give it a shot. Thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: yeah, give it a shot. it will surely give you an ultimate pleasure to code well :)

Answer (score 1):

A hashmapping is not the most efficient way to store things.  Try a Vector or straight arrays.
Hope this Helps

Cliff